# zend 1.11 and doctrine2 proxies not hydrating entity correctly setting fields to null

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with my doctrine 2.0 proxies not hydrating its entity correctly causing the entities fields to return null when calling themn see below:-

snippet from https://github.com/andyfenna/AJF-IT/blob/master/library/AJFIT/ACL/Factory.php line 60

```
foreach($arrRoleResources as $roleResource) { //$roleResouces is a proxy entity

        $role = $roleResource->getRoleFk(); //

        $roleName = $role->getName(); //roleName becomes null even through the pk is populated

}
```

My project is on git hub https://github.com/andyfenna/AJF-IT

The proxy when generated is saved like library\AJFIT\Entity\Proxy\AJFITEntityUserRoleResourcesProxy.php

Should the proxy not be saved like library\AJFIT\Entity\Proxy\UserRoleResourcesProxy.php? or am I missing something?

The proxy class looks like the below and are automatically generated by doctrine.

The UserRoleResources.php entity is saved in library\AJFIT\Entity\

Proxy:- AJFITEntityUserRoleResourcesProxy.php

```
<?php

 namespace AJFIT\Entity\Proxy;

/**
 * THIS CLASS WAS GENERATED BY THE DOCTRINE ORM. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
 */
class AJFITEntityUserResourcesProxy extends \AJFIT\Entity\UserResources implements\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy
{
private $_entityPersister;
private $_identifier;
public $__isInitialized__ = false;
public function __construct($entityPersister, $identifier)
{
    $this->_entityPersister = $entityPersister;
    $this->_identifier = $identifier;
}
/** @private */
public function __load()
{
    if (!$this->__isInitialized__ && $this->_entityPersister) {
        $this->__isInitialized__ = true;

        if (method_exists($this, "__wakeup")) {
            // call this after __isInitialized__to avoid infinite recursion
            // but before loading to emulate what ClassMetadata::newInstance()
            // provides.
            $this->__wakeup();
        }

        if ($this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier, $this) === null) {
            throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException();
        }
        unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier);
    }
}


public function setModule($module)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setModule($module);
}

public function getModule()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getModule();
}

public function setController($controller)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setController($controller);
}

public function getController()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getController();
}

public function setAction($action)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setAction($action);
}

public function getAction()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getAction();
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setName($name);
}

public function getName()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getName();
}

public function setRoutename($routename)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setRoutename($routename);
}

public function getRoutename()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getRoutename();
}

public function setModifed($modifed)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setModifed($modifed);
}

public function getModifed()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getModifed();
}

public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::setCreated($created);
}

public function getCreated()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getCreated();
}

public function getPk()
{
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getPk();
}


public function __sleep()
{
    return array('__isInitialized__', 'module', 'controller', 'action', 'name', 'routename', 'modifed', 'created', 'pk');
}

public function __clone()
{
    if (!$this->__isInitialized__ && $this->_entityPersister) {
        $this->__isInitialized__ = true;
        $class = $this->_entityPersister->getClassMetadata();
        $original = $this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier);
        if ($original === null) {
            throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException();
        }
        foreach ($class->reflFields AS $field => $reflProperty) {
            $reflProperty->setValue($this, $reflProperty->getValue($original));
          }
           unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier);
       }

   }
}
```

Entity:- UserRoleResources.php

```
<?php

namespace AJFIT\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* UserRoleResources
 *
* @Table(name="user_role_resources")
* @Entity
*/
class UserRoleResources
{
/**
 * @var datetime $modified
 *
 * @Column(name="modified", type="datetime")
 */
private $modified;

/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var integer $pk
 *
 * @Column(name="pk", type="integer")
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $pk;

/**
 * @var serResources
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserResources")
 * @JoinColumn(name="resources_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
 */
private $resourcesFk;

/**
 * @var UserRoles
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRoles")
 * @JoinColumn(name="role_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
 */
private $roleFk;


public function __construct() 
{
    $this->roleFk = new ArrayCollection();
}
/**
 * Set modified
 *
 * @param datetime $modified
 */
public function setModified($modified)
{
    $this->modified = $modified;
}

/**
 * Get modified
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getModified()
{
    return $this->modified;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param datetime $created
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return datetime 
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Get pk
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPk()
{
    return $this->pk;
}

/**
 * Set resourcesFk
 *
 * @param UserResources $resourcesFk
 */
public function setResourcesFk(UserResources $resourcesFk)
{
    $this->resourcesFk = $resourcesFk;
}


public function getResourcesFk()
{
    return $this->resourcesFk;
}

/**
 * Set roleFk
 *
 * @param UserRoles $roleFk
 */
public function setRoleFk(UserRoles $roleFk)
{
    $this->roleFk = $roleFk;
}

public function getRoleFk()
{
    return $this->roleFk;
}
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? any help in the matter will be mush apprieciated.

Thank-you

I have included the debug steps that I am going through, hope someone knows whats going on:-

Initial break point

[image: Initial break point]

Step through to proxy

[image: Step through to proxy]

Step through to proxy load

[image: Step through to proxy load]

Hyradation of entity

[image: Hyradation of entity]

Return to proxy

[image: Return to proxy]

Step into entity

[image: Step into entity]

Return to caller (you can see that the variable $roleName is null why??)

[image: Return to caller]

Comment: What do you mean by "corruption"?

Comment: Even though the proxy class ($role) is initiated and the pk is populated from the database when pulling fields using:- $roleName = $role->getName(); (where $role is a proxy class) the code steps through the method getName() but does not return the "name" value from the database at all! what is returned is null, any ideas??

Comment: If someone will take a look at my code i will pay $50 if they can fix it :) https://github.com/andyfenna/AJF-IT

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem? I'm stumbling on that too...

Comment: No did not solve it, could not write a entity to zend auth as the entity becomes a  disconnected proxy and is it impossible hyradting it, so ended up writing the user id to zend auth and reading it to load the full entity from the database, rubbish i know but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue i.e one of my entity property is not storing its value in Database

Root cause was its annotation was incorrect (ie somehow backtick came into annotation)

```
/**` (this backtick is culprit)
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="condition", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
```

If some one facing similar issue, first need to check its annotation part

**p.s:** I know this question is year old but i am answer this because it may help others